# Cross country skiing around Sjusjoen in mid-late April - possible?

Tags: norway, skiing

Wanting to go hut-to-hut in Norway - I'm thinking around Sjusjoen probably best for my first time, ideally just after the half term in April, so about 12-19th.

But I read officially the skiing there stops on April 16th.
I don't mind if it was light snow by that point with grassy patches in spots - could it be any worse than this though?

Comment: The area 'around Sjusjøen' includes elevations between less than 500m and more than 1000m. You have to be more specific with your question. In the lower areas, you will definitely not be guaranteed to have enough snow for skiing by the middle of April.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo So are you saying I can be sure to find some snow 'around Sjusjøen' mid-April if I go high enough?

Comment: No. That was not what I wrote. And it was not what you asked for either. If you want to ski from hut to hut, it won't help you if there is still just snow on the highest peaks.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo So where would you recommend to go to find hut-to-hut cross country skiing mid april in norway? Thankyou